# Highlight org-level-color-stars-only from org-level-2 onwards

Tags: org-mode, font-lock

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18583264/4949315) I have

```
(setq org-level-color-stars-only t)
```

to highlight only the stars in org-mode headings.

However I want to further *customize* the heading coloring. In particular, I want to:

1. Highlight the entire heading until `org-level-2` (that is don't apply `org-level-color-stars t` until `org-level-2`)
2. From `org-level-3` onwards highlight only the stars in the heading (that is apply `org-level-color-stars t` from `org-level-3` and thereafter).

I did `C-h v RET org-level-color-stars RET` and tried reading more and found that, that variable is being used in `org-get-level-face` function in `org.el`. So I think I may have to modify `org-get-level-face`. But I am not that comfortable with `elisp` yet. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many moving parts in face customization ....

I have added comments in the code for what the arg `n` means.  (**NOTE**: The param `n` is not the level, but `n` is the `regex` group.)  You can compare the version of `org-get-level-face--override` here with the original version `org-get-level-face` for the differences.

Additional Note:

- Instead of an `:around` advice, I could have gone for `:filter-return` advice.
- You can remove your  chosen customization  (and revert back to the factory settings) by  putting the cursor at end of `advice-remove` statement and doing `C-x C-e`.

To get this

**For levels 3 or more, only the stars are colored; the headline text is NOT colored**

[image]

do this

```lisp
(advice-add
 'org-get-level-face :override
 (defun org-get-level-face--override (n)
   (let* ((org-l0 (- (match-end 2) (match-beginning 1) 1))
          (org-l (if org-odd-levels-only (1+ (/ org-l0 2)) org-l0))
          (org-f (if org-cycle-level-faces
                     (nth (% (1- org-l) org-n-level-faces) org-level-faces)
                   (nth (1- (min org-l org-n-level-faces)) org-level-faces))))
     (cond
      ((eq n 1)
       ;; face for leading stars
       (if org-hide-leading-stars 'org-hide org-f))
      ((eq n 2)
       ;; face for the last star and space
       org-f)
      (t
       ;; face for the heading
       ;; (unless org-level-color-stars-only org-f)
       (if (<= org-l 2) org-f nil))))))    

;; (advice-remove 'org-get-level-face 'org-get-level-face--override)
```

Comment: Brilliant! The above works. One small mistake: I think there is one extra closing parenthesis in this: `(if (<= org-l 2) org-f nil)))))))`?

Comment: Two follow-up questions: 1. If I want to color until `org-level-k` where `k=1,2,3 ... etc` how should I modify the above script? 2. Can I do a per file customization? Like on some files I want to color it till level-2. But in some other files I want to color it till level-3. I was wondering if I can define something in the `:PROPERTIES:` drawer at the top of the page or define something like `#+color-until` at top of the page? (If you feel question-2 needs it own separate stack-exchange post, I will be happy to post a new question).

Comment: One more follow-up question: For level-3 onwards I _always_ want to color _only stars_. But I don't want to color _full heading_ until level 3 _always_. Instead I want to color _full heading_ **only if** org-level is less than 3 and org-level _has at least one child node_! How do I do this? (Once again, I will be happy to post a separate stack-exchange post on this, if that would be better idea!)

Comment: Or if you feel we can just keep every useful information from this discussion in this post itself, I am also happy to edit _my question_ and add the above follow ups there, so that you can edit _your answer_ and respond to the follows ups there? What do you prefer?

Comment: I could solve question-1: I need to modify `(if (<= org-l 2) org-f nil))))))` to `(if (<= org-l k) org-f nil))))))` where `k=1,2,3...` as the case maybe.

Comment: For question-3: I found `(setq has-children (org-list-has-child-p (point) struct)))` in `org.el`. So I am thinking I need to modify `(if (<= org-l 2) org-f nil)` to something like `(if (and (<= org-l 2) (has-children)) org-f nil)`. But again need a little help with writing _correct_ elisp code. Please help. I think `has-children` is a variable and not a function. So it should not be enclosed in parenthesis? And I think `has-children` may not be within the scope of `org-get-level-face--override` function. So we need to define it again. How can we minimally define it?

Comment: For question-3 I have created a new [emacs stackexchange post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/73847/15780).

Comment: I don't have a ready answer, let me see if I can help in anyway.