# Highlight org headline text only if org-level is less than 3 and has-children

Tags: org-mode, font-lock

This is a follow up to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/73833/15780), which already has an accepted answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73834/15780).

I have

```
(setq org-level-color-stars-only t)
```

to highlight only the stars in org-mode headings.

Following [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73834) I further have

```
(if (<= org-l 2) org-f nil)
```

in `org-get-level-face` function from `org.el`, so that headline is text is colored only if `org-level` is less than equal to 2. (Well, technically in an *override* version of `org-get-level-face` which overrides the original `org-get-level-face` function by an `advice-add` mechanism, as in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73834)).

I want some more *customization*. I want the headline text to be colored **only if**

1. `org-level` is less than equal to 2, (comment: well 2 for example, can be 3,4 etc) and
2. org node/ headline *has children*

So I think I need to modify `(if (<= org-l 2) org-f nil)` to something *like* `(if (and (<= org-l 2) has-children) org-f nil)`. I found this line in `org.el`:

```
(setq has-children (org-list-has-child-p (point) struct)))
```

But I need some help in writing *correct* lisp code. Can you please help?

In particular:

1. `org-list-has-child-p (point)`: does it mean that this function will work only if the cursor/ point is on the headline? I need it to work, irrespective of where the cursor/ point is.
2. Is `has-children` as defined through `(setq has-children (org-list-has-child-p (point) struct)))` a variable of *type* **boolean**? That is, will `(if (and (<= org-l 2) has-children) org-f nil)` be the correct use of the variable `has-children`?
3. I think the variable `has-children` from `org-el` will not be within the *scope* of the *override* version of `org-get-level-face`. So I think we will have to re-define it within its *scope*? How to do that? Will `(setq has-children (org-list-has-child-p (point) struct)))` suffice?

I think I got the *logic* of what I want to do, figured out. But my lack of good understanding of `elisp` is hindering me from implementing it. So, please help.

p.s.: I had asked this question on the comments of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/73833/15780). But I felt making a new post might help it get solved *faster*!

Comment: `org-list-has-child-p` is only applicable to list items, not headlines. I don't know of a built-in way to check that a headline has children (but I haven't looked: there may be one). You should be able to cobble a function together using the `org-element` API. That will be somewhat heavy going  though, so let's hope that somebody knows an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this

**`MY-ORG-LEVEL` is 2**

[image: MY-ORG-LEVEL = 2]

---

**`MY-ORG-LEVEL` is 3**

[image: MY-ORG-LEVEL =3]

do this

1. Copy the snippet below to `my-fontify-headline.el`

```lisp
(require 'org)
(require 'ox)

(add-hook
 'org-mode-hook
 (defun my-org-mode-hook ()
   (unless (featurep 'hi-lock)
     (require 'hi-lock))
   (cl-loop with faces = '(
                           hi-yellow
                           hi-pink
                           hi-green
                           hi-blue
                           hi-salmon
                           hi-aquamarine
                           )
            for i from 1 to (length faces)
            for relative in faces
            for base = (intern (format "org-level-%s" i))
            for relative = (face-remap-add-relative base relative))))

(defun headline-at-point-has-child-p ()
  (org-with-wide-buffer
   (let ((el (org-element-context)))
     (when (and el (eq 'headline (org-element-type el)))
       (let* ((beg (org-element-property :contents-begin el))
              (end (org-element-property :contents-end el)))
         (when (and beg end)
           (string-match (rx (seq bol
                                  (group
                                   (zero-or-more "*"))
                                  (group "* ")))
                         (buffer-substring beg end))))))))

(add-hook 'org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook
          (defun my-org-font-lock-set-keywords-hook ()
            (setcar (cdr org-font-lock-extra-keywords)
                    '(my-org-fontify-headlines))))

(defvar-local MY-ORG-LEVEL org-export-headline-levels)
(put 'MY-ORG-LEVEL 'safe-local-variable 'integerp)

(defun my-org-fontify-headlines (limit)
  (let* ((get-level-faces
          (lambda (org-l)
            (save-match-data
              (let* ((org-f (if org-cycle-level-faces
                                (nth (% (1- org-l) org-n-level-faces)
                                     org-level-faces)
                              (nth (1- (min org-l org-n-level-faces))
                                   org-level-faces))))
                (list
                 ;; face for leading stars
                 (if org-hide-leading-stars 'org-hide org-f)
                 ;; face for the last star and space
                 org-f
                 ;; face for the heading
                 ;; (unless org-level-color-stars-only org-f)
                 (cond
                  ((and (<= org-l MY-ORG-LEVEL)
                        (headline-at-point-has-child-p))
                   org-f)
                  (t nil)))))))
         (case-fold-search t))
    (while (re-search-forward
            (if org-fontify-whole-heading-line
                ;; "^\\(\\**\\)\\(\\* \\)\\(.*\n?\\)"
                (rx (seq bol
                         (group
                          (zero-or-more "*"))
                         (group "* ")
                         (group
                          (zero-or-more nonl)
                          (opt "\n"))))
              ;; "^\\(\\**\\)\\(\\* \\)\\(.*\\)"
              (rx (seq bol
                       (group
                        (zero-or-more "*"))
                       (group "* ")
                       (group
                        (zero-or-more nonl)))))
            limit t)
      (cl-loop with org-l0 = (- (match-end 2) (match-beginning 1) 1)
               with org-l = (if org-odd-levels-only (1+ (/ org-l0 2)) org-l0)
               with faces = (save-excursion
                              (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
                              (funcall get-level-faces org-l))
               for i in '(1 2 3)
               for face in faces
               when face
               do (add-text-properties (match-beginning i) (match-end i)
                                       `(face ,face))))))
```

2. Copy the below snippet to `~/demo.org`

```
* One: No Child
* One
** Two: No Child

Two text

** Two 
*** Three: No Child
*** Three
**** Four: No Child
**** Four
***** Five: No Child
***** Five

# Local Variables:
# MY-ORG-LEVEL: 3
# End:
```

3. `emacs -Q`
4. `M-x load-file RET my-fontify-headline.el RET`
5. `C-x C-f ~/demo.org`
6. Enjoy the view!
7. In `demo.org`, change the value of `MY-ORG-LEVEL` from `3` to `2`. Do `M-x revert-buffer`
8. Enjoy the view!

---

I know nothing about font lock.  So, there is room for improving the snippet.  That said, the snippet illustrates the essential components that will go in to a typical solution.

Comment: Wow - that turned out to be much _harder_ than what I originally imagined it would be. It was _complex_ enough that I wanted to find sufficient time to study it. Very beautiful. Thanks for the snippet! Will build upon it.

Comment: This part of the snippet `(setcar (cdr org-font-lock-extra-keywords)  '(my-org-fontify-headlines))` assumes that the second entry in `org-font-lock-extra-keywords` is a outline regexp, and replaces it.  This assumption may not be true, if you are using some 3rd-party packages that mess with `org-font-lock-extra-keywords`.  Also, it is quite possible that you can append `my-org-fontify-headlines` to the tail of  `org-font-lock-extra-keywords`, and you may get the same results.  (For eg, TODO etc fontification entries occur *after* headline fontification etc.) I was making  things up ....